# Increase Fan Speed on Lenovo 100 Series Laptop

Tags: software-update

How can one increase the fan speed on this laptop through software without doing so with additional hardware. Already tried using Speedfan and looking through the bios but no controls for fan there. Also tried various programs from Lenovo and others to no effect.

Comment: unfourtunately, the large OEMs do not generally allow software on the laptop to alter their built-in cooling policies. I spent years trying to get HPs to be more aggressive about cooling, to no avail.

Comment: Any way to mod the bios safely to reveal additional settings?